# Preventing apps from opening in Lion on reboot

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uncheck “Reopen windows when logging back in” by default](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24783/uncheck-reopen-windows-when-logging-back-in-by-default)

On Mac Lion after reboot, the applications come up immediately. Is there a way to prevent it. From searching over the net, it looks like the user has to disable it explicitly. My problem is I am setting this for a lab at a university and they have many macs. I cannot ask the students to do this individually. I have to set something up. Is this possible ? First of all programmatically(either via applescript or a launchd) ?. Second, if so, is there a good approach ?.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for stackoverflow.  But anyway: defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false

Comment: Sounds like the right place.