# Terminal behaving differently since updating to Lion

Tags: macos, terminal

Ever since my company updated to Lion, terminal.app has been behaving differently. When I click on the dock icon, it sometimes opens several terminal windows at once, instead of a single one, and all of them display my previous session's activity, rather than just opening to a shell prompt.

What can I do to make the terminal go back to behaving the way it used to? I can't find anything in the prefs that would account for these changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer a graphical interface you can use the app [**TinkerTool**](http://bresink.de/osx/0TinkerTool/download.php5).

This application gives you access to additional preference settings and allows to activate hidden features in the operating system.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is great. Generally I prefer command line when I'm on a linux machine, but I'm not as familiar with the actual program names on the Mac so the GUI is really helpful to make sure I'm affecting the correct apps.

Comment: @EmmyS You should accept the answers when they solved your problem :) That way, when searching this site with the search bar, one can see that this has been solved.

Answer (score 7):

This is the [resume](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/) feature of OS X Lion.

### Undo resume for a specific application

Type the following command in the Terminal. Then restart the specific application.

In general the syntax is:

```
defaults write com."producer"."program-name" ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES
```

Thus, in your case (Terminal.app) it is:

```
defaults write com.apple.terminal ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES
```

If you want to set the resume feature again, simply write NO using the same syntax.

### Undo resume for all applications

In order to disable this for *all* applications do this:

go to **`System Preferences->General`**
[image]

Comment: Is there any way (even if I need to do it via terminal command) to set this on a case-by-case basis? There are some apps where I want this behavior, but for most of them I don't.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the solution above.

Comment: I have unchecked the "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps" option but TextEdit still re-opens files I have abandoned the last time I used it. Any ideas?

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm No idea why this is happening. How long has this been going on? I just disabled this feature as well, and I had to restart the tested applications several times to see the change take affect.

Comment: I disabled the feature when I saw it. I didn't even want to know what new terror Apple had tried to bring upon me. However, TextEdit has always re-opened files that I never saved.