# Lion opens lots of windows automatically after a restart. How can I stop that?

Tags: macos, window-manager, resume

Lion opens lots of windows automatically after a restart. How can I stop that?

It's *very* annoying.

Is there a way to stop this?

I found an option in System Preferences ("Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps") and disabled it but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are experiencing are the benefits of working with **resume**. A feature introduced with Mac OS X Lion.

- It restores the state of the computer when shut down. Very useful, when having to restart because of some installation procedure.
- It reopens the used windows of applications. Quite useful since you do not have to navigate to a files location. Instead, just open the needed application to open the file.

Unchecking the box does not have a permanent effect. This can be achieved by manual tweaking.

#### Disable Resume upon login permanently

Open the Terminal and enter:

```
curl http://goo.gl/Z4EFC -L -s -o ~/fixlogin.sh && md5 -q ~/fixlogin.sh | xargs -I % mv ~/fixlogin.sh ~/%.sh && chmod +x ~/121dca51e66073624da420b6e1be61d9.sh && sudo ~/121dca51e66073624da420b6e1be61d9.sh ; rm ~/121dca51e66073624da420b6e1be61d9.sh
```

This command downloads a script and fully installs it. Voilà, you are done.

If you want to revert to the default behavior of resume in lion, type this.

```
sudo defaults delete com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook
```

Kudos to [Hexbrain](http://ikluge.com/2011/08/24/getting-rid-of-lions-application-restore/) who wrote the script.

---

#### Disable Resume when launching apps

You can also disable Resume for applications on a per app basis. [See these answers here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33928/terminal-behaving-differently-since-updating-to-lion/33930#33930)

Comment: I see how the script works. Excellent. Ta.

Comment: You know, OS/2 Warp had this stupid feature in 1994. It was as annoying and unhelpful then as it is know. I can't believe Apple would resurrect a feature from 15 years and sell it as new.

Comment: I believe this is a really good feature. The only thing they could possibly improve, is remembering the selection on checkbox so you don't have to un-tick every time if you don't need it.

Comment: @latusaki I agree 100%. This behavior is inconsistent with other checkboxes you find anywhere in the OS :/. Hence, the workaround in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just uncheck the "Reopen windows when logging back in" checkbox in the restart dialog.

[image]

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't remember the setting.

Comment: Yes, that's a feature - not a bug. To be honest, I agree that this is seriously messed up. Why? Because this behavior is **inconsistent** with the behavior of checkboxes in other system settings.

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox has stayed unchecked in 10.7.4 and later versions. The [release notes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5167) called it an issue, even though it was probably intended behavior originally.

> The OS X Lion v10.7.4 Update includes fixes that:
>
> - Resolve an issue in which the "Reopen windows when logging back in" setting is always enabled.

The state of applications [is still restored even if Resume was disabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39555/unchecking-restore-windows-when-quitting-and-re-opening-apps-doesnt-work) when applications are opened manually or as login items. Disabling `LoginwindowLaunchesRelaunchApps` or `TALLogoutSavesState` doesn't prevent that either.