# How can I have a fixed order of the menu-extras?

Tags: macos, applescript, login-items, menu-bar

Like the OSX menu items for wifi, battery... I would like to be able to have a **permanent order** of the third-party menu bar items.

I do not want to mix OSX with third-party menubar items, I simply want them to always appear in the **same order**.

Setting an order for the menu extras to launch in the startup items does not do the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit:

As it turns out, [disabling resume upon login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34557) is enough.

---

With Applescript, this is a nice solution.

```
set theAppList to {{name:"Growl", vis:false}, {name:"Caffeine", vis:false}, {name:"Boom", vis:false}, {name:"Shimo", vis:false}, {name:"Twitter", vis:false}}
set theDelay to 0.5

repeat with currentApp in theAppList
    tell application (name of currentApp) to launch
    delay theDelay
    tell application "Finder" to set visible of process (name of currentApp) to (vis of currentApp)
end repeat
```

### Important Note

You need to disable resume upon login for this script to work. ("Reopen windows when logging back in").

This can be done permanently with [one line in Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34557).

### How to implement the script

1. Open **AppleScript Editor.app**
2. Paste Script above and customize to your use.
3. Save as Application
   [image]
4. Right-Click on the created application and navigate to `.../Contents/Info.plist` It will open in Xcode.
5. **Menubar -> Editor -> Add Item**
6. Select: **Application is agent (UI Element): YES** and save.
   [image]
7. Add the script to the **Login Items** in the System Preferences.
8. Remove all the Apps that are used in the script from the Login Items.

Comment: It could be easier to save it as a regular script and run it with a launchd agent
(see [How do I run an Automator action, shell script or AppleScript on startup in OS X? - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/373813/how-do-i-run-an-automator-action-shell-script-or-applescript-on-startup-in-os-x))

Answer (score 1):

You can hold command while drag and drop it to change the order. I don't know it will remember the order or not though.

Comment: That only applies for the OSX menu items, not for third-party applications

Comment: @gentmatt In Sierra it works for all of them

Answer (score 1):

In your system preferences if you remove a menu item for whichever program is on there, and then put it back, it will go on the end of the line (left). So you can remove them and then put them all back in the order you want them. Not exactly and elegant solution but it works.

Comment: I've tried this already (see question), but the order for the login items is in no way related to order of the items in the menu bar which is different every time. Also, not all menu items do appear in the login items section.

Comment: Oh I misread, I didn't realize you meant you wanted it that way on login. I don't know a lot about applescripts but I bet there's a way to automate it using applescript?