# How do I move a third-party application's menulet from one location to another in the menu bar?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, menu-bar

I bought [QuickCal 3](http://quickcalapp.com/) from the Mac App Store recently.  Now, when I boot my Mac, the QuickCal menu icon shows on the menu bar, and where it wants to by default, I suppose.

Since QuickCal has the ability to show the current day of the month within its icon, I thought it would work best if **positioned next to my clock.**

I'm trying to save space in my menu bar (I have a lot of crap there already, you'll see), so I have "Show date" turned off for the built-in clock.  But, since I want to have the QuickCal icon, I figure it can do double-duty and add back in the day of the month .. my aging brain can still remember the month, anyway.

So, **how can I accomplish this:**

[image: Screenshot showing my QuickCal menu bar icon and the position I'd like to move it to, next to the clock.]

That is, **how can I reposition a menu icon in the OS X menu bar?**

I tried dragging, but that didn't work.  Is there a way to do this in OS X (e.g. is there a keystroke I need to use *while* dragging?), or some preferences I'm not aware of?

I realize my specific request may be a challenge because I want to move a 3rd party menu item in between two OS X built-in ones (The clock, & battery status.)

Failing that, is there a third party tool I need to add to the multitude I installed already?  In the olden days on Windows XP, I used to have a tool called Taskbar Shuffle that permitted rearrangement of icons in the taskbar and system tray .. anything similar for OS X (but for the menu bar)?

Thanks!

Comment: Command-drag it and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, tried, doesn't drag.  Just opened the QuickCal menu.  :/

Comment: Oh, some third-party menulets don't allow you to move them. AFAIK, your only option would be to re-arrange the other menulets in your menu bar so that the QuickCal menulet is all the way to the right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have a fixed order of the menu-extras?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35023/how-can-i-have-a-fixed-order-of-the-menu-extras)

Answer (score 2):

You can't move it into the same area as the OS icons.  The only way to rearrange the third-party apps is to close programs and re-open them, because they appear in the order the programs were opened.

Comment: They are all launched automatically when I log in.  Is there a way to change that launch order?

Comment: Yes, go to your startup items options and rearrange the order the programs launch in.  Instructions for how to access:  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2602

Comment: Umm...no, actually you can. I can move Menu Meters all the way over to Spotlight.

Comment: @daviesgeek care to share how? For somethings CMD+Drag works, but not for others.

Comment: Actually since then, I found out that Menu Meters uses some sort of plugin to be able to do that. Command-drag works though, for Menu Meters.

Comment: `they appear in the order the programs were opened` seems not to be true. I just tried with f.lux and TODOist. They order was the same no matter the launch order

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this free tool:  [Broomstick](http://www.zibity.com/broomstick).  One of its features is "Customize Order of Menubar Icons."  I was able to use it to reorder some third party menu bar icons, but as @AndrewLatham has noted in his answer, this also wouldn't permit moving a third-party app's menu icon into the area used by the OS X icons.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in macOS Sierra without using any third-party apps. All you need to do is hold the `Command` key down while you click and drag the application icon to another spot in the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to be able to do this is by using [Bartender](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/42632/bartender). It's all I use Bartender for (which makes the $15 price tag seem a little steep); I hide the Bartender icon and disable the other features. But it does a beautiful job of allowing me to command-drag menu bar icons.

Answer (score -1):

Two possible items found at cnet.com ... I haven't tried them myself.

Login Items Engine

Login Control