# Why does my computer auto-restart after freezing (Lion 10.7.3), even when disabled?

Tags: macos, crash, performance

Since recently upgrading to "Lion 10.7.3" I have had repeated instances of the machine hanging/crashing without warning and then silently restarting.

Problem is, that such automatic restarts happen even though I have NOT selected the "Restart automatically if the computer freezes" in "**System Preferences** > **Energy Saver**" (For both power supply and battery profiles) are NOT checked.

**Q**: Why is the system restarting automatically when it freezes/crashes/hangs?

Related question: Is there a difference between freezing, crashing, and hanging, such that the check box only affects "freezing"?

---

Here is the Crash Report (loginwindow_2012-03-02-083729_localhost.crash):

```
Process:         loginwindow [8119]
Path:            /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow
Identifier:      loginwindow
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-03-02 08:36:27.696 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  5

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001099af000-0000000109a3a000 [  556K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow

Application Specific Information:
objc[8119]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff919ec67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff919ebd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff936dc6fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff936e4e64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff936e4676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8a7da31f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8a7e15c9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8a7e1456 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e09bf5d _DPSNextEvent + 659
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e09b861 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e09819d -[NSApplication run] + 470
11  com.apple.loginwindow           0x00000001099b42ee 0x1099af000 + 21230
12  com.apple.loginwindow           0x00000001099b3d9c 0x1099af000 + 19868

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff919ee7e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bf85be _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bf714e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff919edbca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff891992a6 _pthread_cond_wait + 890
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8ccd763f CVDisplayLink::waitUntil(unsigned long long) + 279
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8ccd6aa5 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 559
4   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8ccd685d _ZL13startIOThreadPv + 148
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff891958bf _pthread_start + 335
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff89198b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff89198b78 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.screenlock
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff919ec67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff919ebd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff92b64616 _CGSSetSymbolicHotKeyEnabled + 131
3   com.apple.UniversalAccess       0x000000010aed7167 -[UAZoomDriver(Private) _enableZoomInOutHotKeys] + 42
4   com.apple.UniversalAccess       0x000000010aed6768 -[UAZoomDriver(Private) _startFullScreenZoom] + 50
5   com.apple.UniversalAccess       0x000000010aed4287 -[UAZoomDriver setSuspended:] + 200
6   com.apple.loginwindow           0x00000001099d9c70 0x1099af000 + 175216
7   com.apple.loginwindow           0x00000001099d948d 0x1099af000 + 173197
8   com.apple.loginwindow           0x00000001099d7183 0x1099af000 + 164227
9   com.apple.loginwindow           0x00000001099d7020 0x1099af000 + 163872
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bf68ba _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bf810a _dispatch_queue_drain + 264
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bf7f66 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 54
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bf7760 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 198
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff891973da _pthread_wqthread + 316
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff89198b85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libpam.2.dylib                  0x00007fff88a4ff76 openpam_dispatch + 250
1   libpam.2.dylib                  0x00007fff88a51169 pam_authenticate + 30
2   com.apple.loginwindow           0x00000001099d8822 0x1099af000 + 170018
3   com.apple.loginwindow           0x00000001099d812f 0x1099af000 + 168239
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff877dc74e -[NSThread main] + 68
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff877dc6c6 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff891958bf _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff89198b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff919ee192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff89197594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff89198b85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000004  rbx: 0x00007fcb2b675810  rcx: 0x00000000000d2860  rdx: 0x00007fcb29df7950
  rdi: 0x0000000109a6d400  rsi: 0x00007fcb29d00000  rbp: 0x000000010cc74bf0  rsp: 0x000000010cc74ba0
   r8: 0x0000000000000007   r9: 0x00007fcb29df8020  r10: 0x000000001e919e2b  r11: 0x000000009b21c8eb
  r12: 0x0000000000000003  r13: 0x0000000000000003  r14: 0x0004000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff88a4ff76  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000109d37000
Logical CPU: 1

Binary Images:
>>> SNIP <<<
```

Also, here is the system log around the time of the crash (Paste from All messages tab of Console). Sorry it is so long, But a lot happened there at the end. I included back to a strange message about low mtmd attempting to thin b/c low diskspace and included all the way until a Boingo message, which I know was after the restart b/c I always manually shut it down on restarts (It keeps coming despite being un-checked in Login items, but that is another issue). The full log for the one minute around the time of the crash was too long to include, so I tried trim it to remove duplicate and near duplicate entries. (see the SNIP lines) Here goes:

```
3/2/12 8:34:49.667 AM com.apple.mtmd: attempting to thin because of low free space on Macintosh HD (/) by removing 2012-03-02 15:33:19 +0000
3/2/12 8:36:35.241 AM ReportCrash: DebugSymbols was unable to start a spotlight query: spotlight is not responding or disabled.
3/2/12 8:36:59.208 AM mds: (Error) Server: ==== XPC handleXPCMessage XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID
>>>Snip<<<
3/2/12 8:37:00.068 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x2a92a9].com.apple.AppleSpell[8189]) Job has not died after being cleanly killed 2 seconds ago. Simulating exit.
3/2/12 8:37:00.068 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x2a92a9].com.apple.AppleSpell[8189]) Simulated exit: <rdar://problem/9359725>
3/2/12 8:37:00.087 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x299299].com.apple.Preview[8155]) Job has not died after being cleanly killed 2 seconds ago. Simulating exit.
3/2/12 8:37:00.087 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x299299].com.apple.Preview[8155]) Simulated exit: <rdar://problem/9359725>
3/2/12 8:37:00.833 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua[8141]) Job has not died after being cleanly killed 2 seconds ago. Simulating exit.
3/2/12 8:37:00.834 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua[8141]) Simulated exit: <rdar://problem/9359725>
3/2/12 8:37:00.834 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.talagent[8164]) Job has not died after being cleanly killed 2 seconds ago. Simulating exit.
3/2/12 8:37:00.834 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.talagent[8164]) Simulated exit: <rdar://problem/9359725>
3/2/12 8:37:01.251 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.imagent[8188]) Job has not died after being cleanly killed 2 seconds ago. Simulating exit.
3/2/12 8:37:01.251 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.imagent[8188]) Simulated exit: <rdar://problem/9359725>
3/2/12 8:37:01.251 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.fontd[8170]) Job has not died after being cleanly killed 2 seconds ago. Simulating exit.
3/2/12 8:37:01.251 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.fontd[8170]) Simulated exit: <rdar://problem/9359725>
3/2/12 8:37:01.995 AM UserEventAgent: CaptiveNetworkSupport:UserAgentDied:139 User Agent @port=27187 Died
3/2/12 8:37:03.467 AM Google Chrome Helper: kCGErrorRangeCheck: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
3/2/12 8:37:03.467 AM Google Chrome Helper: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
3/2/12 8:37:03.467 AM Google Chrome Helper: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
3/2/12 8:37:03.467 AM Google Chrome Helper: kCGErrorRangeCheck: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
3/2/12 8:37:03.468 AM Google Chrome Helper: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
3/2/12 8:37:05.859 AM com.apple.launchd: (com.apple.loginwindow[8119]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
3/2/12 8:37:06.614 AM Google Chrome Helper: _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
>>>SNIP<<<
3/2/12 8:37:07.397 AM VMware Fusion Helper: (ipc/send) invalid destination port: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0x10307, 16384 bytes
3/2/12 8:37:07.397 AM VMware Fusion Helper: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
3/2/12 8:37:07.397 AM VMware Fusion Helper: CGSShutdownServerConnections: Detaching application from window server
3/2/12 8:37:07.710 AM zotero: (ipc/send) invalid destination port: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0x17323, 16384 bytes
3/2/12 8:37:07.710 AM Dock: (ipc/send) invalid destination port: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0x12603, 16384 bytes
3/2/12 8:37:07.710 AM zotero: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
3/2/12 8:37:07.710 AM Dock: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
3/2/12 8:37:07.710 AM zotero: CGSShutdownServerConnections: Detaching application from window server
3/2/12 8:37:07.710 AM Dock: CGSShutdownServerConnections: Detaching application from window server
3/2/12 8:37:07.733 AM eclipse: (ipc/send) invalid destination port: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0x15c9f, 16384 bytes
3/2/12 8:37:07.733 AM eclipse: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
3/2/12 8:37:07.733 AM eclipse: CGSShutdownServerConnections: Detaching application from window server
3/2/12 8:37:08.412 AM zotero: (ipc/send) invalid destination port: CGSReleaseShmem : Cannot release shared memory
3/2/12 8:37:08.412 AM Dock: (ipc/send) invalid destination port: CGSReleaseShmem : Cannot release shared memory
3/2/12 8:37:08.424 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: CGSDisplayServerShutdown: Detaching display subsystem from window server
>>> SNIP <<<
3/2/12 8:37:08.673 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSWindowAddRegionToDirtyShape: Invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:08.673 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSFlushWindowContentRegion: Invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:08.730 AM [0x0-0x7a67a6].com.google.Chrome: [27585:24071:536717962443764:ERROR:gpu_watchdog_thread.cc(234)] The GPU process hung. Terminating after 10000 ms.
3/2/12 8:37:08.824 AM zotero: CGSDisplayServerShutdown: Detaching display subsystem from window server
3/2/12 8:37:08.825 AM zotero: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSFlushWindowContentRegion: Invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:08.825 AM zotero: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
3/2/12 8:37:08.825 AM zotero: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
3/2/12 8:37:08.852 AM zotero: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSFlushWindowContentRegion: Invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:08.880 AM eclipse: (ipc/send) invalid destination port: CGSReleaseShmem : Cannot release shared memory
3/2/12 8:37:08.927 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSWindowAddRegionToDirtyShape: Invalid connection
>>> SNIP <<<
3/2/12 8:37:09.140 AM [0x0-0x7a67a6].com.google.Chrome: 2012-03-02 08:37:09.138 Google Chrome Helper[27844:207] HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
3/2/12 8:37:09.140 AM [0x0-0x7a67a6].com.google.Chrome: 2012-03-02 08:37:09.140 Google Chrome Helper[27844:207] port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
>>>SNIP<<<
3/2/12 8:37:09.412 AM com.apple.dock.extra: (ipc/send) invalid destination port: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0xea03, 16384 bytes
3/2/12 8:37:09.412 AM com.apple.dock.extra: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
3/2/12 8:37:09.412 AM com.apple.dock.extra: CGSShutdownServerConnections: Detaching application from window server
>>> SNIP <<<
3/2/12 8:37:09.878 AM com.apple.dock.extra: (ipc/send) invalid destination port: CGSReleaseShmem : Cannot release shared memory
3/2/12 8:37:09.932 AM X11.bin: (ipc/send) invalid destination port: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0x1f6b3, 16384 bytes
3/2/12 8:37:09.950 AM X11.bin: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
3/2/12 8:37:09.950 AM X11.bin: CGSShutdownServerConnections: Detaching application from window server
>>> SNIP <<<
3/2/12 8:37:09.965 AM eclipse: CGSDisplayServerShutdown: Detaching display subsystem from window server
>>> SNIP <<<
>>>SNIP<<<
3/2/12 8:37:10.720 AM com.apple.dock.extra: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
3/2/12 8:37:10.720 AM com.apple.dock.extra: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
3/2/12 8:37:10.720 AM com.apple.dock.extra: 2012-03-02 08:37:10.720 com.apple.dock.extra[8177:1707] HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
3/2/12 8:37:10.721 AM com.apple.dock.extra: 2012-03-02 08:37:10.720 com.apple.dock.extra[8177:1707] port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
>>> SNIP <<<
3/2/12 8:37:10.966 AM GoogleTalkPlugin: kCGErrorRangeCheck: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
3/2/12 8:37:10.966 AM GoogleTalkPlugin: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
3/2/12 8:37:10.966 AM GoogleTalkPlugin: kCGErrorRangeCheck: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
3/2/12 8:37:10.966 AM GoogleTalkPlugin: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
>>> SNIP <<<
3/2/12 8:37:12.921 AM eclipse: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
3/2/12 8:37:13.133 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
3/2/12 8:37:13.134 AM Dock: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSSetBackgroundEventMaskAndShape: Invalid connection
>>>SNIP<<<
3/2/12 8:37:12.892 AM login: DEAD_PROCESS: 13776 ttys003
3/2/12 8:37:13.135 AM [0x0-0x7a67a6].com.google.Chrome: 2012-03-02 08:37:10.018 Google Chrome Helper EH[19593:b03] HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
3/2/12 8:37:13.135 AM [0x0-0x7a67a6].com.google.Chrome: 2012-03-02 08:37:13.134 Google Chrome Helper EH[19593:b03] port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
>>> SNIP <<<
3/2/12 8:37:13.805 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.Dock.agent[8163]) Exited with code: 1
3/2/12 8:37:13.806 AM zotero: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetWindowMouseLocation called with invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:13.806 AM zotero: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetWindowBounds: Invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:13.806 AM zotero: PScurrentwindowbounds: CGSGetWindowBounds returned error (1002)
3/2/12 8:37:13.807 AM zotero: kCGErrorRangeCheck: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
3/2/12 8:37:13.807 AM zotero: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
3/2/12 8:37:13.807 AM zotero: kCGErrorRangeCheck: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
3/2/12 8:37:13.807 AM zotero: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
3/2/12 8:37:13.861 AM ChronoSyncBackgrounder: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSUnregisterWindowWithSystemStatusBar: Invalid window
3/2/12 8:37:13.861 AM ChronoSyncBackgrounder: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
3/2/12 8:37:13.861 AM ChronoSyncBackgrounder: ChronoSync Backgrounder v4.2.4 has terminated.
3/2/12 8:37:13.888 AM quartz-wm: CGSDisplayServerShutdown: Detaching display subsystem from window server
3/2/12 8:37:13.945 AM eclipse: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetWindowMouseLocation called with invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:13.945 AM eclipse: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetWindowBounds: Invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:13.945 AM eclipse: PScurrentwindowbounds: CGSGetWindowBounds returned error (1002)
3/2/12 8:37:14.001 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: kCGErrorRangeCheck: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
3/2/12 8:37:14.001 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
>>> SNIP <<<
3/2/12 8:37:15.203 AM login: DEAD_PROCESS: 13775 ttys001
3/2/12 8:37:15.276 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: kCGErrorRangeCheck: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
3/2/12 8:37:15.277 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
3/2/12 8:37:15.277 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: kCGErrorRangeCheck: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
3/2/12 8:37:15.277 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
3/2/12 8:37:15.374 AM login: DEAD_PROCESS: 8193 ttys000
3/2/12 8:37:15.574 AM X11.bin: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSFlushWindowContentRegion: Invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:16.487 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x2ae2ae].com.econtechnologies.backgrounder.chronosync[8251]) Exited with code: 1
3/2/12 8:37:16.945 AM X11.bin: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetWindowMouseLocation called with invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:16.945 AM X11.bin: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetWindowBounds: Invalid connection
3/2/12 8:37:16.946 AM X11.bin: PScurrentwindowbounds: CGSGetWindowBounds returned error (1002)
3/2/12 8:37:16.946 AM X11.bin: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetWindowMouseLocation called with invalid connection
>>>SNIP<<<
3/2/12 8:37:17.314 AM Google Chrome: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=12 label=[0x0-0x9f69f6].com.apple.ImageCaptureExtension2 path=/System/Library/Image Capture/Support/Image Capture Extension.app/Contents/MacOS/Image Capture Extension flags=0
3/2/12 8:37:17.774 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x7cc7cc].com.google.GoogleTalkPluginD[19594]) Exit timeout elapsed (20 seconds). Killing
3/2/12 8:37:17.774 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x7a67a6].com.google.Chrome[19526]) Exit timeout elapsed (20 seconds). Killing
3/2/12 8:37:17.850 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x680680].org.lyx.lyx[17352]) Exit timeout elapsed (20 seconds). Killing
3/2/12 8:37:17.850 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x2ad2ad].com.vmware.fusionDaemon[8250]) Exit timeout elapsed (20 seconds). Killing
3/2/12 8:37:19.774 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x7a67a6].com.google.Chrome[19526]) Job has not died after being killed 2 seconds ago. Simulating exit.
3/2/12 8:37:19.774 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x7a67a6].com.google.Chrome[19526]) Simulated exit: <rdar://problem/9359725>
3/2/12 8:37:19.924 AM Google Chrome Helper EH: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=22 label=[0x0-0x9f79f7].com.google.GoogleTalkPluginD path=/Library/Application Support/Google/GoogleTalkPlugin.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleTalkPlugin flags=0
3/2/12 8:37:20.314 AM Google Chrome Helper: Our bootstrap port disappeared out from under us: 2563 { urefs = 32773, rights = 0xa03: dead name }
3/2/12 8:37:20.315 AM Google Chrome Helper: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (268435459)
3/2/12 8:37:20.315 AM Google Chrome Helper: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (268435459)
3/2/12 8:37:20.315 AM Google Chrome Helper: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (268435459)
3/2/12 8:37:20.907 AM Google Chrome Helper: Bug: 11D50: libxpc.dylib + 27798 [D40B8FD1-C671-3BD5-8C9E-054AF6D4FE9A]: 0x5
3/2/12 8:37:23.883 AM xpchelper: for uid: 0 -- timeout while waiting on FSEvents flush; clearing cache.
3/2/12 8:37:29.777 AM ReportCrash: Saved crash report for loginwindow[8119] version ??? (???) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/loginwindow_2012-03-02-083729_localhost.crash
3/2/12 8:37:29.798 AM loginwindow: Login Window Application Started
3/2/12 8:37:30.000 AM kernel: (default pager): [KERNEL]: default_pager_backing_store_monitor - send LO_WAT_ALERT
3/2/12 8:37:31.271 AM loginwindow: **DMPROXY** Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
3/2/12 8:37:31.704 AM com.apple.usbmuxd: stopping.
3/2/12 8:37:31.959 AM com.apple.usbmuxd: usbmuxd-263 on Nov 14 2011 at 18:58:10, running 64 bit
3/2/12 8:37:34.140 AM airportd: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “default”. Bailing on auto-join.
3/2/12 8:37:35.226 AM com.apple.SecurityServer: Session 100049 created
3/2/12 8:37:35.229 AM loginwindow: Login Window Started Security Agent
3/2/12 8:37:36.445 AM SecurityAgent: Echo enabled
3/2/12 8:37:36.445 AM SecurityAgent: Echo enabled
3/2/12 8:37:36.580 AM com.apple.launchctl.LoginWindow: com.apple.findmymacmessenger: Already loaded
3/2/12 8:37:40.660 AM WindowServer: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
3/2/12 8:37:45.470 AM SecurityAgent: User info context values set for bpalmintier
3/2/12 8:37:45.470 AM SecurityAgent: User info context values set for bpalmintier
3/2/12 8:37:46.674 AM SecurityAgent: Login Window login proceeding
3/2/12 8:37:46.674 AM SecurityAgent: Login Window login proceeding
3/2/12 8:37:46.788 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMounter mountHomeDirectoryForUser:atPath:homeLocation:] | name = bpalmintier, path = /Users/bpalmintier, homeLoc = (null)
3/2/12 8:37:46.788 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMounter setNeedsToUnmountDirVolumeAtLogout:] | mounter calling mechanism to setNeedsToUnmountDirVolumeAtLogout to 0
3/2/12 8:37:46.788 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMounter mountHomeDirectoryForUser:atPath:homeLocation:] | urlAttribute = null
3/2/12 8:37:46.788 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMounter mountHomeDirectoryForUser:atPath:homeLocation:] | homeDirPath did NOT follow a symlink, keeping original path of: /Users/bpalmintier
3/2/12 8:37:46.788 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMounter mountHomeDirectoryForUser:atPath:homeLocation:] | homeDirMajorType = 1
3/2/12 8:37:46.789 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMounter mountStandardDirectoryForUser:atPath:attributes:] | name = bpalmintier, path = /Users/bpalmintier, homeLoc = (null)
3/2/12 8:37:46.789 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMechanism isGuestAccount] | enter
3/2/12 8:37:46.789 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMechanism isGuestAccount] | Guest account check returning 0
3/2/12 8:37:46.789 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMounter setHomeDirType:] | setHomeDirType to 1
3/2/12 8:37:46.789 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMounter mountStandardDirectoryForUser:atPath:attributes:] | returning 0
3/2/12 8:37:46.789 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMounter mountHomeDirectoryForUser:atPath:homeLocation:] | returning 0
3/2/12 8:37:46.789 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMechanism invoke] | mountHomeDirectoryForUser returns 0
3/2/12 8:37:46.789 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMechanism updateAndUnlockKeychain] | updateAndUnlockKeychain
3/2/12 8:37:46.789 AM authorizationhost: DEBUGLOG | -[HomeDirMechanism launchHomeDirFixerToolIfNeeded:] | launchHomeDirFixerToolIfNeeded called with 0
3/2/12 8:37:47.388 AM loginwindow: Login Window - Returned from Security Agent
3/2/12 8:37:47.475 AM loginwindow: USER_PROCESS: 28592 console
3/2/12 8:37:48.207 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.ReportCrash) Falling back to default Mach exception handler. Could not find: com.apple.ReportCrash.Self
3/2/12 8:37:48.210 AM com.apple.launchctl.Aqua: com.apple.AirPortBaseStationAgent: Already loaded
3/2/12 8:37:48.214 AM com.apple.launchctl.Aqua: load: option requires an argument -- D
3/2/12 8:37:48.214 AM com.apple.launchctl.Aqua: usage: launchctl load [-wF] [-D <user|local|network|system|all>] paths...
3/2/12 8:37:49.456 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.launchctl.Aqua[28614]) Exited with code: 1
3/2/12 8:37:51.562 AM UserEventAgent: CaptiveNetworkSupport:CNSServerRegisterUserAgent:187 new user agent port: 30391
3/2/12 8:37:51.662 AM eclipse: Failed to create window context device
3/2/12 8:37:51.757 AM eclipse: CGWindowContextCreate: failed to create window context delegate.
3/2/12 8:37:51.757 AM eclipse: _initWithWindowNumber: error creating graphics ctxt object for ctxt:0x15c9f, window:0x722c
3/2/12 8:38:04.891 AM [0x0-0x9fd9fd].com.google.Chrome: [0302/083804:INFO:breakpad_mac.mm(137)] Breakpad disabled
3/2/12 8:38:11.058 AM eclipse: Failed to create window context device
3/2/12 8:38:11.058 AM eclipse: CGWindowContextCreate: failed to create window context delegate.
3/2/12 8:38:11.058 AM eclipse: _initWithWindowNumber: error creating graphics ctxt object for ctxt:0x15c9f, window:0x722c
3/2/12 8:38:18.867 AM zotero: -[NSPersistentUIManager snapshotWindow:handler:]: CGSGetSurfaceCount(cid, wid, &surfaceCount) returned error 1002 on line 2401
3/2/12 8:38:18.867 AM zotero: __CGPixelAccessLockWindowAccess: access lock failed: error 1002.
3/2/12 8:38:24.505 AM com.apple.dock.extra: Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication
3/2/12 8:38:24.505 AM com.apple.dock.extra: 2012-03-02 08:38:24.503 com.apple.dock.extra[28654:1707] Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication
>>>SNIP<<<
3/2/12 8:38:49.839 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (fm.last.lastfmhelper[28704]) posix_spawn("/Applications/Last.fm.app/Contents/MacOS/LastFMHelper", ...): No such file or directory
3/2/12 8:38:49.840 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (fm.last.lastfmhelper[28704]) Exited with code: 1
3/2/12 8:39:02.448 AM eclipse: -[NSPersistentUIManager snapshotWindow:handler:]: CGSGetSurfaceCount(cid, wid, &surfaceCount) returned error 1002 on line 2401
3/2/12 8:39:02.448 AM eclipse: __CGPixelAccessLockWindowAccess: access lock failed: error 1002.
3/2/12 8:39:12.868 AM ChronoSyncBackgrounder: ChronoSync Backgrounder v4.2.4 is running.
3/2/12 8:39:21.860 AM Boingo Wi-Finder: importSettings
```

Comment: What does the system log say around the crash time?

Comment: We will need to see the crash log to determine the culprit here. Evidently the crash is at kernel level or above user land.

Comment: @Robin I've included (excerpts from) the system log around the time of the crash.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini: Update-- I posted the head of the crash log in hopes that it helps. Let me know if you need other parts.

Comment: @BryanP I've taken a look through the logs... can't see anything to indicate your system has shutdown/restart at all. You would expect to see the 'shutdown' process. The loginwindow process is crashing which can look like a restart (all apps quit, menubars disappear, blue screen... followed by it logging in again). Archive and install would be easiest, aka start up from recovery partition and install without wiping your HDD.

Comment: @Robin Oh, that must be it! I hadn't realized that after a successful login, there still was a login process that runs. What you describe: all apps & other items quit, blank screen, then login prompt is exactly what I've had. Write your comment up as an answer and I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the logs that you've posted it looks like the loginwindow process is crashing for some reason. This will cause your machine to log out and present the login window, all of which could appear similar to your machine restarting.

As for a fix, I'd suggest an archive + install. There is probably a corrupt preference (or similar) causing the crash but it may not be that simple... So to save time/effort, boot from your recovery partition and reinstall the OS. I'd be quite surprised if that didn't fix the problem.

In answer to your related question, I'd have to say 'I don't know' but launchd (or maybe the kernel) probably watches a few key processes and restarts the system when crash/hang is detected. In previous versions of server an option existed for a restart if a kernel panic occurs, this may be a renaming of that option for OS X client.