# Lion apps opening previous files

Tags: macos

When I open apps like Textedit, Preview or MS-Word in Lion - they also open documents that were open last time I closed the application.

Is there a way of stopping this? Generally if I'm opening an app I'd like it to, as most, give me a new blank document or file...

Comment: Your question is related to [this question here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/33928/13414).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [**resume**](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/) feature of OS X Lion.

You can use [**TinkerTool**](http://bresink.de/osx/0TinkerTool/download.php5) do disable resume on a per-app basis.

Besides this, TinkerTool gives you access to additional preference settings and allows to activate hidden features in the operating system.

I've also explained how to disable resume using the Terminal [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/33930/13414).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable this on a global basis in System Preferences / General.

[image: System Preferences / General screenshot]