# How do I prevent my Mac from opening so many windows every time I restart?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I have to restart my Mac all the time because I'm using Boot Camp and switching in between Windows 8 and OS X. Every time I restart and come back to OS X, my screen gets flooded with open windows, every thing from Firefox to text editors. Is there any way to set it up  so that there are no open windows upon restart?

Comment: I've added an answer to disable this function on a *permanent* basis. Current answers require you to click the checkbox on **every** shutdown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you go to shutdown/restart, unclick the check box to disable the resume feature, which is likely what is opening all these windows (that were present upon shutdown).

[image]

If this doesn't do it, check that these applications are not in your user start up list.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## Disable Resume on login *permanently*

What you are experiencing are the benefits of working with **[Resume](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/)**. A feature introduced with Mac OS X Lion to restore windows upon next launch or login.

[image]

**Unchecking the box does *not* have a permanent effect**. This can be achieved by manual tweaking.

Open the Terminal and enter:

```
curl http://goo.gl/Z4EFC -L -s -o ~/fixlogin.sh && md5 -q ~/fixlogin.sh | xargs -I % mv ~/fixlogin.sh ~/%.sh && chmod +x ~/121dca51e66073624da420b6e1be61d9.sh && sudo ~/121dca51e66073624da420b6e1be61d9.sh ; rm ~/121dca51e66073624da420b6e1be61d9.sh
```

This command downloads the following [script](http://ikluge.com/2011/08/24/getting-rid-of-lions-application-restore/) and fully installs it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "#!/bin/bash" > /tmp/loginfix.sh
echo "rm /Users/*/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.loginwindow.*" >> /tmp/loginfix.sh
mv /tmp/loginfix.sh /usr/bin/loginfix.sh
chmod +x /usr/bin/loginfix.sh
defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /usr/bin/loginfix.sh
```

**Et voilà, you are done!**

If you want to revert to the default behavior of Resume in lion, type this.

```
sudo defaults delete com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook
```

## Disable Resume when launching apps

You can also disable Resume for applications on a *per app* basis. [See these answers here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33928/terminal-behaving-differently-since-updating-to-lion/33930#33930)

Comment: +1, but I suggest you include the source for that script in your answer.  The thought of executing a script sight-unseen and downloaded from a shortened link makes me nervous :-)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea No problem. I've edited my post :)

Comment: Is there a way to get this script working for network user accounts?

Comment: @GeertHuylebroeck If you want, that might make a great full question on the site - just link back to here, explain you want to craft this script for another use and explain what's failing. Our guides on [ask] and [about] should help.

Comment: I found that some items in the dock had "Open at Login" checked (right click dock icon > Open at Login), removing that stopped them popping up at login.

Comment: The site hosting the script seems to no longer exist. Fortunately you can just deny yourself permissions to that plist file, which I've written up [as an answer on the first copy of this question I found](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253609/202172)

Comment: after you disabled it permanently is there a way to enable it on demand?

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices. You can choose that your applications not resume their previous state when you shutdown or restart the Mac by deselecting the checkbox that appears prior to shutdown:

[image: image of Shutdown Dialog box]

Or you can navigate to the **General** pane in System Preferences and deselect the *Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps* option. However, if you do this, applications will never resume their previous state, even when quit and restarted during a single *boot* session.

[image: image of General Preferences Pane]

Comment: The "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps" option is not available in Mountain Lion (10.8.2). Has that been moved elsewhere?