# Can I stop mac 10.8 from saving previous open programs/finder windows after power shutdown?

Tags: macos, finder, shutdown

I think what I'm looking for is a .plist file.

specifically what I want, is it possible to clear whatever files saves last opened windows that are re-opened on startup that get saved after a shutdown from the power button or general power failure without disrupting general use.

Comment: Have you tried the solution mentioned here? -> http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/44607/61192

Answer (score -1):

other than wth terminal you can try omyx http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx