# How can I prevent macOS from restoring all applications after a hard reboot?

Tags: macos, startup, high-sierra, preferences

At least in macOS 10.13, if my iMac reboots due to a kernel panic or when a software update requires a reboot, the system restarts the applications that were running immediately before the shutdown *even if I have unchecked the "restore windows when logging back in"* checkbox in the restart dialog the last time I was shown that dialog.  (Of course, upon a hard reboot, this dialog is not shown anyway.) Restarting all applications automatically is **exactly the wrong thing to do** if the problem was *caused* by the applications running at the time.

I want to turn off this application restoration feature completely. How can I achieve this?

Note that I do not want to prevent the system from restoring the windows of the aplications that I start and stop deliberately. My settings in Systems Preferences ➜ General are the following:

[image]

I **never** want the applications I was running to be *restarted* automatically for me, apart from those that are in the list of "Login Items" in my User & Groups system preferences.

Comment: This was answered on a different site here: https://superuser.com/questions/338004/prevent-mac-from-reloading-apps-after-restart

Comment: There's a different solution provided in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230719/how-to-disable-app-relaunch-and-window-restore-in-el-capitan-on-reboot

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I'm now attempting one of the solutions now and am waiting for another occasion when my Mac reboots due to a software update or other situation to really test it.