# How to permanently disable app relaunch and window restore in Mojave on reboot?

Tags: macos, mojave, reboot

How do I disable both the "relaunch apps after reboot" feature as well as the "reopen windows at relaunch" feature? When I reboot (be it after a hard reset or reboot command) I want to be presented with a blank desktop and not everything I had open before. This is the same as [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230719/how-to-disable-app-relaunch-and-window-restore-in-el-capitan-on-reboot) regarding doing this on El Capitan, but the trick does not seem to work on Mojave (the commands go through, but there is no effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://superuser.com/questions/338004/prevent-mac-from-reloading-apps-after-restart

> What you are looking for is to disable ApplePersistence feature, which can be done with:
>
> ```
> defaults write -g ApplePersistence -bool no
> ```