# How do I speed up Mac boot to the ready desktop in El capitan

Tags: macos, startup, performance, restart

My computer has become slow to fully boot since updating to 10.11. This isn't helped by Applications (including their previous windows) reopening automatically post login. I am aware that this is part of the default Mac OS experience and I've seen answers that involve checking a box when restarting, although I would prefer a permanent fix to disable this particular function and any other advice to improve my iMacs startup efficiency.

Comment: Permanent stoppage of re open is covered here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20651/reopen-windows-when-logging-back-in-not

Comment: @bmike That doesn't cover El Capitan. Thigns have changed since those answers.

Comment: Are you trying to circumvent "saved application state " entirely or just app launch? If you can call out specifically what step you decided to take from the other linked question and/or refine the specific issue, I'd be inclined to cast a reopen vote.

Comment: If your question is the same and you need new answers - putting a bounty on the original question is the way the site is designed to work.

Comment: @bmike That's asking for a temporary solution.