AppleScript (Music.app) error: Can't get duration of current track
I have a simple AppleScript for starting a random video on a random position in Music.app as Automator application and as a startup login item. In the half of cases I get an error:
The action "Run AppleScript" encountered an error: "Music got an error: Can't get duration of current track."
If I run it in the Script Editor it executes correctly.
I tried to add "delay 5" before the line "set Y to duration of current track" but it didn't help. Also tried to add "if" condition to quit Music.app if it is running before starting the script, but it also didn't change anything.

tell application "Music"
    run
    set song repeat to all
    set shuffle enabled to true
    play playlist "Music Videos"
    delay 1
    set Y to duration of current track
    set X to random number from 0 to Y
    set player position to X
    activate
end tell

The error often appears on the next day if system was shutdown with the script:
tell application "Finder" to shut down

I guess this is somehow related to the running state of Music.app on the moment of shutting down the system, since after system startup all apps return to the same state they were before shutting down, e.g. if I close all my apps and restart the system using Apple logo > Restart the script will be executed correctly and I won't see any errors on the screen.
macOS Ventura 13.4
Thanks a lot

Seems the last solution from this topic helped to get rid of lot of reopening apps with every startup and thus ease the execution of the script: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460943/282457

It's weird having to re-enable automator app in Privacy & Security > Accessibility everytime it has been changed, but so far found only a terminal shortcut to open  its window to make it a bit faster:
open "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility"

